# 4N35 difference between two versions

Tags: phototransistor

Would like to know the difference between these two 4N35 optocouplers .
They behave differently but cannot find what is related the "001Q" and "027Q" digit.

[image]

Comment: I would normally expect a date code in that position. Often in the form of a Year/Week. It is usually 4 digits though.

Comment: ...and behaving in a different way??

Comment: `behave differently` is a vague, useless description of observed behavior ... how do the two components behave? ... please add the schematic of the test circuit

Comment: In what way are they behaving differently?  There's a wide variation in CTR from part to part (esp. from different lots) so could be normal process variation.

Comment: @Ken90 - Just FYI (since other site members are suggesting you to add to the question): If you want to ask about the difference in behaviour you are seeing (whatever that is) and if you can provide schematics, measurements, analysis etc. that would be a reasonable question. However it would need to be asked as a *new* question, as it's too late to change *this* question from its original request to explain the different top codes.

Comment: Is it purely the photo, or does one of those lack (or have a different) pin-1 marker?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - It would seem to be the photo. The IC on the right *does* have the same pin-1 marker, you just may have to adjust contrast to see it better

Comment: @Greenonline Just checking :-) Somebody on Youtube highlighted a consignment of chips that all had the same markings (yea verily, even unto the last digit of the date) despite using obviously-different encapsulation and leg styles.

Comment: The circle around the ON logo looks misprinted on both parts (gap above the N on the left part, double line below/left of the O on the right part). That's often a strong hint that at least one of these parts is fake (possibly both). Where did you buy these? If they came from $random_big_online_marketplace instead of a reputable specialized parts supplier, they're very likely fakes and investigating them further is a waste of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented, the different lines "001Q" and "027Q" are just date and assembly codes.

[image: Top markings on OnSemi 4N35 opto-coupler]

Image source: [OnSemi 4N35 Optocoupler Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/4n35-d.pdf)

The two optocouplers *should* behave the same. If they don't, then either they are damaged, fake, being operated outside their specifications, or the difference is within specifications.

Comment: thanks. Will open another topic with different behavior problems eventually

Comment: /Should/ behave the same within the operational ranges specified by the datasheet. It's definitely not safe to measure the parameters of one and expect others- even assuming they're genuine- to behave the same to the last microamp.

Answer (score 0):

the 4n35 to my knowledge has a few "edits" or versions since the first ed, from which it has been perfected. so the newer ones are likely more "linearized" in the optical current conversion. there's only a few "edits" of the old one 4n35. the newer ones are more linearized but also suffer a narrower slope.